# Eliminate single quoted strings using SED in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, sed

In my file I have the contents like below.

```
<sql type="cognos">SELECT * FROM  [PG WIND JAROS - JAROSODS].AGREMENT_MAS WHERE FILTER = 'Saravana' and ADDress = '32/36 Abc Nagar CH' </sql>
<sql type="cognos">select OBJECT_TYPE           'Object Type',
 OBJECT_NAME            "Object Name",
from [PG WIND Jaros - JAROSDM].CX_WIND_LOOKUP_REF WHERE Filter = 'Kumaar' and STATUS = 'RICH' </sql>
```

Here I have to convert everything to lower case except strings in single quotes. i.e.,

output:

```
<sql type="cognos">select * from  [pg wind jaros - jarosods].agrement_mas where filter = 'Saravana' and address = '32/36 Abc Nagar CH' </sql>
<sql type="cognos">select object_type           'Object Type',
 object_name            "object name",
from [pg wind jaros - jarosdm].cx_wind_lookup_ref where filter = 'Kumaar' and status = 'RICH' </sql>
```

How can I acheive this in SED ? Please help me .....

Comment: I would prefer to have the SQL keywords in uppercase. 
Is it a one-time conversion, that you can change manually? 
(In vi use ~)

Comment: No its not one time change.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one  `awk` solution:

```
awk -F\' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s"(NF==i?RS:FS),(i%2?tolower($i):$i)}' file
<sql type="cognos">select * from  [pg wind jaros - jarosods].agrement_mas where filter = 'Saravana' and address = '32/36 Abc Nagar CH' </sql>
<sql type="cognos">select object_type           'Object Type',
 object_name            "object name",
from [pg wind jaros - jarosdm].cx_wind_lookup_ref where filter = 'Kumaar' and status = 'RICH' </sql>
```

Comment: @user3459079 I do not have the knowledge for that, and my guess is that it will be complicated.  You do not have `awk`?  Nearly all system with `sed` do also have `awk`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
sed -e "s/^\([^']*\)$/\L\1/" -e "s/\([^']*\)\('[^']*'\)/\L\1\E\2/g" -e "s/\('[^']*\)$/\L\1/" file
```

`\L` turns the replacement to lower case (until `\E` is found).

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: I am not sure if `sed` is the proper tool for this job. Jotnes `awk` solution is much shorter.

Comment: what does \E refers to ?

Comment: See `sed` man page: `\E`: Stop case conversion started by `\L` or `\U`.